# Libraries and tools for Characterization/Golden Master Testing

Tags: automated-testing, regression-testing, characterization-testing

I really like [Characterization/Golden Master Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterization_test), but I'm only aware of the [ApprovalTests](http://approvaltests.sourceforge.net/) library. I wonder if there're more libraries and tools that embrace the paradigm. I'm looking for facilities to

- store and compare the golden master.
- use generators similar to [QuickCheck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickCheck).
- create characterization tests on system level.
- …

Language/platform doesn't matter—any suggestions?