# (Visual) testing of the geographic/GIS maps functionality using Protractor

Tags: protractor, angular, image-based-testing

I'm preparing an automated system/end2end tests for the AngularJS application using Protractor.
One part of the application, that I'm going to test, displays geographical maps.

I need to verify for example whether:

- searching for the particular location works properly (and appropriate map is displayed),
- when I search for the features that matches particular criteria, they will be visualized on the map.

---

I wonder what is suggested approach for testing of the GIS/maps functionality.
Should I create a print screen for the expected part of the map and then try to find on the screen part of map that matches such image?
Is [protractor-image-comparison](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-image-comparison) suggested package to use?

On SQA I found this question: [Is there a dancing pony on the screen? (Visual testing)](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/29735/is-there-a-dancing-pony-on-the-screen-visual-testing) to be useful, but if possible I would like to avoid introducing completely separate testing tool sets.